# Are generalized quadrangles the only known triangle free partial linear spaces

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, reference-request

I've been using triangle-free partial linear spaces often in my research, to build triangle-free graphs for example. I have been told by people far more competent in that domain that generalized quadrangles are the only known triangle free partial linear spaces (perhaps with the additional constraint of having order $(s,t)$ and removing trivial/degenerate examples.)

Am I curious about the general acceptance of this fact. Is anyone aware of some counter-example? or some potential ones even, I'd be happy to dig it up. I couldn't find any info online (e.g. nothing in https://www.mathcounterexamples.net/)

**Some definitions**. A *partial linear space* is an incidence structure of points $\mathcal{P}$ and lines $\mathcal{L}$, with an incidence relation such that there is at most one line through every pair of distinct points. If there are no three distinct lines pairwise meeting each other in three distinct points, then the partial linear space is *triangle-free*.

If every line is incident with exactly $s+1$ points and every point is incident with exactly $t+1$ lines, then the partial linear space has order $(s,t)$.

A (finite) *generalized quadrangle* $\mathcal{Q}$ of order $(s, t)$ is an incidence structure of points $\mathcal{P}$, lines $\mathcal{L}$, together with a symmetric point-line incidence relation satisfying the following axioms:

1. Each point lies on $t+1$ lines ($t\ge 1$) and two distinct points are incident with at most one line.
2. Each line lies on $s+1$ points ($s\ge 1$) and two distinct lines are incident with at most one point.
3. If $P$ is a point and $\ell$ is a line not incident with $P$, then there is a unique point on $\ell$ collinear with $P$.

Notice that the third axiom above ensures that there are no triangles, hence generalized quadrangles are triangle-free partial linear spaces.

Comment: You can also consider generalised hexagons and generalised octagons. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygon